# param not found: first_name | ActionController::ParameterMissing in LegaciesController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, parameters

I am getting the error: `param not found: first_name | ActionController::ParameterMissing in LegaciesController#create`

On

```
private
    def link_params
      params.require(:first_name).permit(:id, :last_name, :legacy_donations, :address, :city, :state, :zip_code, :gender, :date_of_birth, :Marital_status, :Spouses_name, :comments)
    end

end
```

This is my controller

```
class LegaciesController < ApplicationController

    def index
    end

    def new
        @legacy = Legacy.new
    end

    def create
        @legacy = Legacy.new(link_params)
        if @legacy.save
            redirect_to @legacy
        else 
            render action: 'new'
        end
    end

    def show
    end

    def destroy
    end

    def edit
    end

    def update
    end

private
    def link_params
      params.require(:first_name).permit(:id, :last_name, :legacy_donations, :address, :city, :state, :zip_code, :gender, :date_of_birth, :Marital_status, :Spouses_name, :comments)
    end

end
```

And this is my legacies/new view:

```
%= form_for @legacy, html:{ role: "form", class: "new-legacy"} do |f| %>
  <% if @legacy.errors.any? %>
      <div id="error_explanation">
          <h1><%= pluralize(@legacy.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this from being saved:</h1>

              <ul>
                  <% @legacy.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                        <li><%= msg %></li>
                  <% end %>
              </ul>
      </div>
  <% end %>

            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :First_Name %><br />
                <%= f.text_field :first_name, class:"form-control", placeholder:"First Name" %>
              </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :Last_Name %><br />
                <%= f.text_field :last_name, class:"form-control", placeholder:"Last Name"  %>  
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
              <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :Last_Name %><br />
                <%= f.text_field :last_name, class:"form-control", placeholder:"Last Name"  %>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
              <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :Last_Name %><br />
                <%= f.text_field :last_name, class:"form-control", placeholder:"Last Name"  %>    
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
              <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :Address %><br />
                <%= f.text_field :address, class:"form-control", placeholder:"Adress"  %>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
              <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :City %><br />
                <%= f.text_field :city, class:"form-control", placeholder:"City"  %>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
              <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :State %><br />
                <%= f.text_field :state, class:"form-control", placeholder:"State"  %>
              </div>            

              <div class="form-group">
              <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :Zip_Code %><br />
                <%= f.text_field :zip_code, class:"form-control", placeholder:"Zip Code"  %>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
              <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :Gender %><br />
                <%= f.text_field :gender, class:"form-control", placeholder:"Gender"  %>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
              <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :DOB %><br />
                <%= f.date_field :date_of_birth, class:"form-control", placeholder:"DOB"  %>  
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
              <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :Marital_Status %><br />
                <%= f.text_field :gender, class:"form-control", placeholder:"Marital Status"  %>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
              <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :Spouses_Name %><br />
                <%= f.text_field :gender, class:"form-control", placeholder:"Spouses Name"  %>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
              <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :Legacy_Donations %><br />
                <%= f.text_field :legacy_donations, class:"form-control", placeholder:"Legacy Donations"  %>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
              <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :Comments %><br />
                <%= f.text_field :comments, class:"form-control", placeholder:"Comments"  %>
              </div>

              <div class="actions">
                <%= f.submit class:"btn btn-default new-eurekamoment-button" %>
              </div>
              <% end %>

            </div>
```

Whats the deal am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
def link_params
    params.require(:legacy).permit(:id, :first_name,:last_name, :legacy_donations, :address, :city, :state, :zip_code, :gender, :date_of_birth, :Marital_status, :Spouses_name, :comments)
end
```

Comment: Thank you! That works, i misunderstood link_params function will accept answer once it allows me to